# Magento 2: Consequences of not Naming a plugin class `\Plugin`

Tags: magento2, plugin

Are there any consequences for using a plugin class in Magento 2 that doesn't end in `\Plugin`?  The [docs suggest](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) that this class should end in the name `\Plugin`.

> The name of a plug-in’s class or its virtual type. Use the following schema when you specify this element: \Plugin.

However, there's several code plugins that **don't** follow this.

```
<!-- #File: app/code/Magento/Weee/etc/frontend/di.xml-->
<plugin name="weee-app-action-dispatchController-context-plugin"
        type="Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin"/>
```

Are there any programmatic consequences to not using `\Plugin` in your class name?  Or is this just a convention -- similar to Magento 1's `_Observer` class name convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the official training slides/instruction say "The name of a plugin class or its virtual type; uses the naming convention \Plugin.".  However, the solutions guide for the exercises creates a plugin without following that convention.  So unless something has changed architecturally, I would say this is just a convention

Answer (score 3):

In *magento-2* ,The usage of plugin name in the classname is just a convention and is not mandatory as we use the observer class name.

The following is generalized syntax code of plugin :

```
<plugin name="plugin_name" type="class_name" />
```

where the `type` just holds the class name which needs to be instantiated.